# How to pass values across managed beans one annotated with @Named and the other @ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I used the primefaces crud generator in my application, and the Controllers generated are annotated with @Named. I would like to access the a value in the *TblCasePersonController* from my own created bean *ForwardCaseBacking* but this gives me an exception as shown below. I tried to change the annotation from @Named to @ManagedBean it still doesn't work.,

**This is  TblCasePersonController**

```
@Named(value = "tblCasePersonController")
@SessionScoped
public class TblCasePersonController extends AbstractController<TblCasePerson> {

private TblCasePerson selected;
public TblCasePersonController() {
    super(TblCasePerson.class);
}

@Override
public TblCasePerson getSelected() {
    //Get the selected CasePerson
    selected = super.getSelected(); 

    TblCase tblCaseId = new TblCase();
    tblCaseId.setId(super.getIdOfSubmittedRecord());
    selected.setTblCaseId(tblCaseId);

    return selected;
}
```

**This is ForwardCaseBacking**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ForwardCaseBacking implements Serializable {

private int caseId;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{tblCasePersonController}")
private TblCasePersonController tblCasePersonController;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
  if(tblCasePersonController.getSelected()!=null){
        caseId = tblCasePersonController.getSelected().getId();
    }
}
```

***I get this Exception***

**exception**:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create managed bean forwardCaseBacking.  The following problems were found:
     - Property tblCasePersonController for managed bean forwardCaseBacking does not exist.  Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.

**root cause**:
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed bean forwardCaseBacking.  The following problems were found:
     - Property tblCasePersonController for managed bean forwardCaseBacking does not exist.  Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.

Comment: Why not make `ForwardCaseBacking` a `@Named` bean?

Comment: Check if you have getter a setter for `tblCasePersonController` in `ForwardCaseBacking`. If not, try add its.

Comment: Did you check the root cause? `Property tblCasePersonController for managed bean forwardCaseBacking does not exist. Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.` Basically, you miss the setter method for `tblCasePersonController` in your `ForwardCaseBacking`

Comment: @VasilLukach. Thanks. I added the getter and setter and it worked fine.

Comment: @XtremeBiker. Thanks, I think I really did not carefully see what the root cause was telling me to do. After adding the property, it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add setter and optionally a getter for `tblCasePersonController` in `ForwardCaseBacking`.